# How do I use fold left on a list of x:Myclass => Boolean to get the conjunction?

Tags: scala, fold

I have some filters expressed as a list of function List(MyClass => Boolean) . Im trying to get the logical conjunction (AND) of all the members . I have a feeling, I could use a fold here .but Im not getting the syntax especially around how to pass the MyClass argument to the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple. Assuming your `List(MyClass => Boolean)` of functions is named `predicates and`MyClass`you are testing is named`myClass`:

```
val result: Boolean = predicates.foldLeft(true) {
  (value, predicate) => 
    value && predicate(myClass)
}
```

Or in a wrapping function:

```
def conjunction(myClass: MyClass, predicates: List[MyClass => Boolean]) = 
  predicates.foldLeft(true) {
    (value, predicate) => 
      value && predicate(myClass)
  }
```

Explanation: if you list of predicates consists of three functions: `foo(myClass: MyClass): Boolean`, `bar(myClass: MyClass): Boolean` and `buzz(myClass: MyClass): Boolean` the code above is roughly equivalent to:

```
((true && foo(myClass)) && bar(myClass) && buzz(myClass)
```

I wrote an article a while ago about [such use cases of `foldLeft`](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/04/secret-powers-of-foldleft-in-scala.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `foldLeft` here, but `forall` is a lot nicer:

```
def check[A](filters: Seq[A => Boolean])(a: A) = filters.forall(_(a))
```

Which works as follows:

```
scala> val filters = Seq[Int => Boolean]((_ > 0), (_ % 2 == 1), (_ < 1000))
filters: Seq[Int => Boolean] = List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>)

scala> check(filters)(10)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> check(filters)(103)
res1: Boolean = true
```

It has the additional advantage of being lazy:

```
scala> check(filters :+ { i: Int => print(i); true })(10)
res2: Boolean = false
```

The last filter (which has a side effect) isn't applied, since the second fails.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's consider two such predicates:

```
val pa: T => Boolean = ???
val pb: T => Boolean = ???
```

The conjunction of them would be like this:

```
val pab: T => Boolean = (v: T) => pa(V) && pb(v)
```

From there you have the formula for the fold:

```
list.tail.foldLeft(list.head) {
  case (pa, pb) => v => pa(v) && pb(v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`predicates.foldLeft( true ) ( _ && _( myClass ) )` might also work.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in these cases is to use the "Pimp-My-Library" pattern to add boolean operations over predicates, which are just the boolean operations on the results lifted to the obvious boolean combinators over the predicates. Thus I can say something like

```
import MyRichPredicate;

val f:Int=>Boolean = (x:Int)=>x%3==0
val g:Int=>Boolean = (x:Int)=>x%5==0
val h = f && !g  //equivalent to (x:Int)=> x%3 == 0 && x%5!=0
print(h(9)) // prints true
print(h(15)) // prints false
```

Given that sort of plumbing, the fold you want can be written as

```
predicates.foldLeft(x=>true)(_&&_)
```

or even more sexily

```
predicates.reduce(_&&_)
```